# Why Travis-CI and composer execute query during clear:cache (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, composer-php, travis-ci

I try to configure Travis-ci with symfony (not easy !). When I run composer install, just after download all package, composer try to clear the cache, and execute a SQL query (why?), and, don't find the table (the migration command is after). I don't understand, why composer try to execute a query.

This is the code in travisci.yml:

```
install:
  - cp .env.dist .env
  - mysql -e 'create database testing;'
  - composer install

after_install:
- php ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
- php ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
#- php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
#- php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -n --env=test
#- ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit install
- ./bin/phpunit install
```

and the result :

```
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug                       
!!   // true                                                                        
!!  
!!  
!!  In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 62:
!!                                                                                 
!!    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.created AS   
!!    created_2, t0.updated AS updated_3, t0.name AS name_4, t0.source AS source_  
!!    5 FROM twig_template t0 WHERE t0.name = ? LIMIT 1' with params [{}]:         
!!                                                                                 
!!    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.twig_tem  
!!    plate' doesn't exist                                                         
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  In PDOStatement.php line 144:
!!                                                                                 
!!    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.twig_tem  
!!    plate' doesn't exist                                                         
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  In PDOStatement.php line 142:
!!                                                                                 
!!    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.twig_tem  
!!    plate' doesn't exist                                                         
!!
```

or here in details: https://travis-ci.org/Dannebicque/intranetV3/builds/455840273

Thanks for your help
David

Comment: You're most likely interacting with database in the constructor of a service. When the container is built during cache warmup, each dependency is instantiated. Move database interaction out of constructor and you should be fine.

Comment: OK thanks. Now it works If I comment the line below, but how can I modify this service ? 

```
<?php
class DatabaseTwigLoader implements \Twig_LoaderInterface
{
    private $twigTemplateRepository;

    public function __construct(TwigTemplateRepository $twigTemplateRepository)
    {
        $this->twigTemplateRepository = $twigTemplateRepository;
    }

    protected function getValue($name)
    {
        //return $this->twigTemplateRepository->findOneBy(['name' => $name]);
    }
}
```